# I want to play multiple audio files at the same time using JavaSound but my threaded application skills are rusty

Tags: java, concurrency, javasound

I'm starting a little Java app that uses a collection of individual piano note audio samples to do ear training (recognizing notes/intervals). The audio samples are .aiff files and are no more than a minute long each. I'm trying to be able to play individual samples, as well as play groups of samples concurrently, if possible.

I have executed this example:
https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-play-back-audio-in-java-with-examples

and I've had some luck playing individual audio samples using this example.

However, it's ugly to get successive samples to play, and I've had no luck getting concurrent samples to play.

Here's an idea of the API I'm going for:

Instrument (abstract class):

```
public void playNote(String note)   // Plays single audio sample from start to finish

public void playChord(List<String> notes)   // Plays concurrent samples together from start to finish
```

I've got a Piano class which extends Instrument, and which maps to specific audio files but I've left the "playing" logic to the instrument class.

Do I need a Mixer to play multiple notes? It seems like I might need one Line per sample, and Mixers appear to be used for multiple Lines.

Would anyone be able/willing to point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Store each sample in a Clip. When you call play on a Clip, it plays in its own daemon thread. There is no need to create individual threads for each play. No reason you can't call three play methods at once for a chord. Yes, I looked at the referenced links for "duplicate" and found the answers there both unclear and disputatious, hence my answering here. Reminder: you have to reset each Clip that has been played back to frame 0 before playing it again.

Comment: If you need to get into mixing, you might consider a library like TinySound or (my) AudioCue, both on github. But from your description, Clips could well be adequate to the task.